# Unable to view my hat selection

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash-2014

According to the Winter Bash icon above, I've earned the Saint Lucia hat on both Math.SE and Meta.SE; however, when attempting to view it on either site, I'm faced with [this screen](http://puu.sh/duZlO/3a6324d8a7.png). Checking the developer's console, I see I've received an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendTo' of undefined cdn-prom.sstatic.net/WinterBash/js/core.js:2

I'm able to view others' hat screens perfectly well.

For what it's worth, I'm using Version 38.0.2125.104m of Chrome on Windows 7.

Comment: It's also not working for me on Chrome Version 39.0.2171.95m on Windows 8.1 and I'm getting the same error in console

Comment: Anything else in the dev console? Failed HTTP requests etc?

Comment: @balpha I'm seeing nothing else, but perhaps I don't know how to use the console properly. [Here's](http://puu.sh/dv0sj/82f2a1630c.png) a screenshot.

Comment: Nah, in the Chrome console it would be bright red, hard to miss.

Comment: @balpha It's the only line showing up in my console as well

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For users who have chosen "Identicon" for their profile picture, the document structure is slightly different; this wasn't taken into account. Fixed now.

Comment: Thanks. Restarting my browser after this fixed it.